# The keyboard comes in front of the flutter HTML editor -FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, html-editor

My problem is that the Keyboard comes in front of the HTML text editor widget when the keyboard opens. I make the whole page scrollable when the keyboard opens. it works on normal text fields, text area widgets but not works on flutter Html editor. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

This is the screenshot of the issue. [image: Image attached shows the issue]

```
 return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
    top: 14,
  ),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 1.5, top: 14),
        child: Text(
          "Enter Message",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
              color: MyColor.textColor),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 3,
            right: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 1),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 3,
          right: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 3,
          bottom: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 3,
        ),
        child: HtmlEditor(
          hint: "Your text here...",
          key: keyEditor,
          height: 400,
          useBottomSheet: false,
          showBottomToolbar: false,
        )
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

This is my code

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the html editor inside a `Container` and setting the `margin` to `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`. Like this:

```
Container(child: YourHtmlEditor(),
margin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,)
```

Comment: HTML editor already wrapped inside a container and also given the margin.
My code is given above, please look at that and tell me what are changes needed

Comment: `margin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`, has to be exactly like this. The `margin` you added won't work.

Comment: margin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets    used this one but not working

Comment: Try putting the margin on the Container you added a top margin of 14. (the first one)

Comment: I tried that too, but not working. This widget placed inside a column and this column wrapped inside a SingleChildScrollView . I think the margin is not a problem.

Comment: Can you suggest which is good HTML editor plugin in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Hello There's a solution maybe will help you

1. First Configure your Scaffold by adding :

   ```
     resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   ```
2. Change The Column With ListView
3. Wrap The Html Editor with container and setup The margin to :

   ```
     margin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
   ```

Happy Coding !